# ComboBoxItem not showing selected item smartgwt

Tags: java, combobox, smartgwt

i've a simple combobox item contained in a Dynamicform made with smartgwt. I've populated the dropdown list with the resultset of some query to the database and it is correctly populated. Then I've set some handler to manage the fact that the combobox is populated based on an other combobox of the for, and it is specifically an onFocus Handler which gives the message to populate at first the first required combo and only then the file combo (the combo in question). The problem is that now i have the populated list and the onfocus event without errors but i cannot select anything in the combo cause whatever i select the row of the selection always remains empty.

This is weird, i don't even get any error in development mode to see if something is wrong.

I'm pasting the code of the combo:

```
fileComboBox.addFocusHandler(new FocusHandler(){

        @Override
        public void onFocus(FocusEvent event){
            String society = (String) getCompany();
            if(society==null || society.equals(EMPTY_STRING)){
                SC.say(constants.selezionaSocieta());
        }
            companyComboBox.focusInItem();
    }});

    fileComboBox.setTitle(constants.fileUploadMov());
    fileComboBox.setName(FILE);
    fileComboBox.setValueField(TestataDS.ATTR_ID_UPLOAD); 
    fileComboBox.setDisplayField(TestataDS.ATTR_NOME_FILE);
    fileComboBox.setAutoFetchData(false);
    fileComboBox.setFetchMissingValues(false);
    fileComboBox.setOptionDataSource(TestataDS.getInstance());

fileComboBox = new ComboBoxItem() {
     @Override
           protected Criteria getPickListFilterCriteria() {

         return getFileCriteria();

    }};

    public AdvancedCriteria getFileCriteria(){
    String society = (String) getCompany();
    String societyValue = ( society != null) ? society : "";
    Criterion cSociety = new Criterion("codSocGest", OperatorId.EQUALS, societyValue);
    return new AdvancedCriteria(OperatorId.AND, new Criterion[]{cSociety});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it turning the combobox into a selectItem